# Android programming -text display

Tags: android

I'm beginner in android programming. I have to display large text (7-8 paragraphs) in text view. My question is - shall i write text in string.xml or write a text file to phone's memory or sdcard and then display the text?? Which one is better? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If text is static then write text in string.xml.

Comment: isn't it your logic ,writing text file in to sdcard and then display in your screen quite lengthy !!! ? -@Pr9 ,Any way if it is static then just do it in your xml hard coded  or in side your java file , or in the case of dynamic just set response in your textview

Answer (score 0):

write text in string.xml because no different if you write in text file . In string.xml also write paragraph